# O(nm + n2 log n) complexity time polynomial time?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

If an algorithm computes in O(nm + n^2 log n) time. Can you then say it computes in Polynomial time?

I know that O(n log n) is O(n^2) so polynomial time. Just not sure how the n^2 works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that O(n) means "upper-bounded". If a function T(n) is O(n), then n*T(n) is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Of course, you can also multiply T(n) by some other function that is O(n) --- not necessarily f(n)=n. So T(n)*O(n) is also O(n<sup>2</sup>).

If you know that O(n logn) is O(n<sup>2</sup>), then you can multiply both by a function that is O(n) and arrive to the conclusion that O(n<sup>2</sup> logn) is O(n<sup>3</sup>), which is polynomial.

Finally, if O(a), O(b) and O(c) are all polynomials, then O(a+b+c) is also polynomial. Because they can all be upper-bounded by the term that grows faster.